# MySQL create table with set attribute from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner at this but is it possible (in MySQL workbench) to create an attribute that is a set depended on an attribute from another table?

```
CREATE TABLE danes (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    nationality VARCHAR(20),
    gender CHAR(1),
    degree SET ?????????????????? from degree(level)
);

CREATE TABLE degree (
    level VARCHAR(10),
    subject VARCHAR(20),
    institutionawarding VARCHAR(20),
    yearawarded DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (level, subject)
);
```

never mind I got it

Comment: Are you talking about a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to achieve. Which degree's level should show up on an individual "danes" when there is no link between them? Or are you asking how to link them?

Comment: +1 to @GordonLinoff's answer, but the reason this doesn't work is that it would require new values in `degree.level` to alter the definition of the SET. What happens when there are more than 64 distinct values of `level`? (The MySQL SET data type is limited to 64 elements.)

Comment: well baiscly I want to create the attribute but I dont know how the SET type works if it can be use like linking the attibute to level of the table degrees or I acually have to create a new one i don't know

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you want another table, a junction table:

```
CREATE TABLE DaneDegrees (
    DanesId INT REFERENCES danes(id),
    Level VARCHAR(10),
    Subject VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_level_subject(level, subject) REFERENCES Degree(level, Subject)
);
```

I would, however, have an `INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` in both `Danes` and `Degrees`.

Answer (score 0):

apparently you cant just say

<*attribute_name*> set(get set from another tabe)

the set thing doesn't work that way

eventhough you can apparently update it so it actually can

update *table_name*

*attribute* = (select * from *another table_name*)